# PHP, sendmail and transports - how to speed up mail sending

Tags: php, zend-framework, email, sendmail, zend-mail

I just wrote a set of bulk-emailing classes for handling enormous amounts of emails and parsing their content according to passed params. If I test an email on 1000 random recipients and 1000 random senders from my database, up until the point the script hits the send() part (I commented it for now), I get performance of around 2 seconds, and 20 MB peak memory, which is great.

However, if I uncomment the send part, the sending takes 30 seconds. This is unacceptable, and I would like to speed it up somehow. It is obvious from testing that the delay is caused by none other than the $mail->send() call, as if it's waiting for it to return something before continuing the loop and sending the next email.

What I'm wondering is: how do I speed up the send() call? What can I do to make it faster? I tried using two sending methods:

1. Zend SMTP transport, connecting to the server directly and just sending. This takes 30 seconds per 1000 emails.
2. Sendmail via Zend_Mail. Simply calling Zend_Mail's send function after preparing each email. This takes 60 seconds.

Please note that queueing is definitely an option, and I have built it into my classes. All it takes is activating a cron and it works like a charm. But I'm wondering about the actual sending and how to speed that up. So, the actual send() call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd save the mails in a directory and send them using a shell script (cron/daemon/...):

```
Zend_Mail::setDefaultTransport(
    new Zend_Mail_Transport_File(
        array(
            'path' => __DIR__,
            'callback' => function() {
                do {
                    $file = 'email-' . date('Y-m-d_H-i-s') . '_' . mt_rand() . '.eml';
                } while (file_exists($file));
                return $file;
            },
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but a good MySQL query will always outdo a file reading. The queueing mechanism is already done either way, and needs no improvement right now. Likewise, our emails are each with a different content. So while we are sending 1000 emails in 2 seconds, each of those has a different recipient, different sender and different content. I believe this aspect you displayed here can be useful in bulk emailing only, yes? Where the content is identical in all the messages? If not, the question still remains - could this be faster than queueing in the database? I'm skeptical.

Comment: I thought that the problem is SENDING not GENERATING! :) There may be some optimised mail server, that would be able to bulk-load gazzilions of messages. Anycase - it would be faster than the php's sendmail method. Direct server access should be many times fater than php will ever be (it can for example use persistent connection).

Comment: Hmmm, quite right. A prepared email could easily be saved to disk in eml format, and from then on a script would take over. This could also serve decently as an alternate queue. Do you have any examples of this being done in an efficient manner? I would love to have a look at some.

Comment: No, actually not. I use the above code to dump mail instead of sending on development machine. I guess you can have a RAMDisk/SSD for saving those emails and then the only thing you need is to find a server capable of sending from directory at decent speeds ;)

Comment: But for extreme preformant solution I'd suggest bypassing Zend completly and dump the email yourselves, because there are some tests, encoding, etc. that you may not need which slow down the email creation. But doing that now, would be premature optimalization. :)

Comment: I'd first try switching sendmail transport with above solution to see if sendmail is the bottleneck in the send() call. If filesaving is MUCH faster I'd go with that outmail directory solution. Otherwise I guess that it's ZF, what's slowing the sending down... ;)

Comment: happy to hear that ! :) Might be awesome to make it available as OSS (github?) some time later and probably make a mail adapter for ZF for that (that I would volunteer to do). I guess that would be useable for many other users ;)

Comment: I'll definitely consider it if the company lets me open source it.

Comment: @Swader I'm in a similar situation right now trying to speed up the sending time of my emails. i send about 4 emails a second at 150kbs an email using sendmail. Do you have an example of your Go programs that sends emails? It would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You will need to speed up the MTA on the server. I recommend Postfix and that you really read up on each setting so you know how to fine-tune it. For a commercial solution I've heard PowerMTA is a good choice but I've never tried it myself.

There's only so much performance you can squeeze out of one machine, but a regular dedicated server should be able to deliver a rather impressive amount of mail once you've configured it correctly. The biggest performance bottleneck is usually the disk drives where the mail queue is stored, so consider using SAS (10k or even 15k RPM) or SSD drives.

Comment: I will definitely look into this. Our email output will be increasing significantly very soon, and such a step up might be quite necessary.

Comment: We have begun planning this approach, but we will also include Tomas' answer into our solution. It has actually proven incredibly awesome, so far.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to dig into PHP [pcntl-fork](http://php.net/pcntl-fork) function. Thus you could leave the sending in another process while parsing the next email.

**PLAN B**

You can serialize and save the email object into a database queue and let another script to send them in the background. This script could run in infinite loop (`while true`) with some `sleep` on every iteration. You can even run multiple instances of this script, but be sure that two scripts won't start sending the same email simultaneously.

To be sure that the script is still running you can use [monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/) on Unix machines. It is able to start the script if the old instance has failed for some reason.

Comment: Hmm, this looks very appealing, but isn't it a fact that PCNTL functions are unavailable if PHP is run as an Apache module? I seem to recall reading something about that somewhere, but cannot find the information any more. Also, PCTNL is unavailable on Windows machines, and I develop this app on all kinds of OS, depending where I am at a given moment..

Comment: I am already using this type of queueing. The email data is serialized and saved to the DB with the given priority. The cronjob then handles the sending periodically by fetching 500 of the top priority emails every 15 minutes, and it seems to be all good. But what I really want is just speeding up the send() function, and a dedicated server would probably just be the only and best long-term solution.